# Lost assets hashes when edit httpFontsPath

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-usemin, grunt-contrib-compass

So my production project path is different than my dev one. Therefore I have to edit the assets path in the compass config:

```
httpFontsPath: '/different/path/styles/fonts'
```

However, the built css file looks like this:

```
/different/path/styles/fonts/MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.eot
```

instead of this:

```
/different/path/styles/fonts/3efc3fcc.MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.eot
```

And if I omit that compass config line, the output is this:

```
/styles/fonts/3efc3fcc.MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.eot
```

**Why do I lose the hashes when I edit httpFontsPath??**

*Note: my gruntfile is based on [generator-angular 0.7.1](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/tree/6638dd8425e76e6a63e750e071840018897356bc)*